# How to set a radiobutton checked by default in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, radio-button, default

how can I set a default checked radiobutton in react native? I'm trying to have a radio button already activated when the user enters the screen. Thanks for your help. II lready read that I have to use the value prop, but I do not now where to place it correctly, so that its working.

```
 render(){

    return (
      
        <form>
       <View>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="category"
              value="anfaenger"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "anfaenger"}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
            
            />
            Anfänger
          </label>
        </View>
       <View style={{marginTop:10}}>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="category"
              value="geuebt"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "geuebt"}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
            />
            Geübt
          </label>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginTop:10}}>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="category"
              value="eingeschraenkt"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "eingeschraenkt"}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
            />
            Eingeschränkt
            </label>
            </View>
      </form>
      </View>
    
      <View style={{magrinTop:'40'}}>
      <button className="btn btn-default" type="submit">  
          Sichere Auswahl 
        </button>
      <Button  title="Erstelle meinen Plan" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Uebungen', {
               category: this.state.selectedOption, 
              }) }/>
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `defaultChecked` prop to a radio button component like so

```
export default function App() {
  return (
<form>
  <View>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="category"
        value="anfaenger"
        onChange={this.onValueChange}
        defaultChecked
      />
      Anfanger
    </label>
  </View>
  <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="category"
        value="geuebt"
        onChange={this.onValueChange}
      />
      Geubt
    </label>
  </View>
  <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="category"
        value="eingeschraenkt"
        onChange={this.onValueChange}
      />
      Eingeschrnkt
    </label>
  </View>
</form>
  );
}
```

The `value` prop is passed on to the next page when the form is submitted. So if the first option is selected, 'anfaenger' will appear in the form results.

---

Edit:

You're right, the `defaultChecked` prop is only compatible with Web devices, not iOS and Android devices. When running on iOS and Android, I also noticed that some of the tags you used aren't compatible with React-Native, such as `<forms>`, `<input>`, `<label>`, unless there is a library that supports this. However, I wasn't able to find a library where you could import these components from.

Here is an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kaushalp/c25964) I made that holds some code for radio buttons (styling need a bit of work, but maybe you can find a better UI library other than `react-native-paper`).

Basically, I set my React Hook's initial state to the first option in the form. This means that when the user opens the form, the first option should always be checked, since that is the state of the Hook.

If in fact your code does work as originally posted, I'd recommend setting your components `selectedOption` state variable to one of the options in the form.

```
state = {
     selectedOption: 'anfaenger', // or 'geuebt' or 'eingeschraenkt' or any value you want to be the default
}
```

That way, when it checks for the state being a value in the radio button's status, it will be met and marked. However, if you need `selectedOption` to initialize to some value other than those in the radio buttons, then you can do boolean logic like so:

(Assuming `selectedOption` initializes to `''` a.k.a empty string):

```
checked={this.state.selectedOption === "" || this.state.selectedOption === "anfaenger"}
```

Comment: Hm it looks logically, but somehow it does not work...

Comment: @Fi-cyber I edited my original post. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Hey, your code is working. But I used classes instead of hooks. Do you think this is bad aswell? Do you think this is working for crossplattform web applications? I was used to classes because of Java and so I wanted to use it futhermore. When I try to integrate your code in the class it says invalid hook call. Can you give me a recommendation if I should change all my classes to hooks? Or give me an example with a class structure?

Comment: This is what worked out for me: https://snack.expo.io/@cyber_fi/a96fbd

Comment: My code wasn't fully tailored to your situation and wasn't meant to be used, it was just meant to serve as an example. I tried to explain what you should do in the edit, where I mentioned setting the component's state like `state = { selectedOption: 'anfaenger' }`, and then checking for its current value like `{this.state.selectedOption === "anfaenger"}`. My apologies if this was confusing. There isn't any substantial benefit of using functional components over class components, or vice versa. There are definitely use cases for each.

Comment: You can read more [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components). For testing on other platform devices, I would recommend compiling your code on something like Expo so that you are able to get some perspective for iOS and Android devices. By the way, it looks like your posted Snack achieves your desired behavior with a default marked radio button, with a class component! Good job :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Currently I am working on registrating my app. It still cause problems. But thanks for everything.

Comment: No problem, feel free to continue this thread if you run into more issues. If this helped, can you mark this response as the answer?